# NetworkX edges do not connect with node borders but instead edges start and end in node center

Tags: python, networkx

My NetworkX visualization edges do not connect with the node borders but instead edges start and end in node center.

The edges do connect with the node borders by setting `arrows=True`. However, I do not want arrows.

When I set `arrows=False` the edges do not connect with the node borders but instead edges start and end in node center as shown in screenshot.

Without arrows edges start and end in node center

[image: NetworkX visualization without arrows]

With arrows  edges start and end on node border

[image: NetworkX visualization with arrows]

There are a handful of other similar questions but the answers are not helping.

One suggests defining nodes a second time which doesn't fix this for me.

Another one suggests using `zborders` and it doesn't seem suited to my situation.

There must be a simple fix for this? It seems such a basic feature.

As code indicates I have dynamic node size and edge weight which may be part of my issue?

```
nx.draw_networkx(
    G, 
    pos,
    ## nodes
    node_color='red',
    alpha=0.7,
    edgecolors='white', #color of node border
    node_size=[(d[node]+1) * 200 for node in G.nodes()],
    linewidths=1.0, #width of node border
    with_labels=False,
    ## labels
    font_color='white',
    font_size=10,
    font_family='sans-serif', 
    font_weight='normal',
    horizontalalignment='center', 
    verticalalignment='center', 
    ## edges
    edgelist=edges,
    edge_color='white',
    edge_cmap=plt.cm.spring,
    width=counts, #1.0, #width of edge
    arrows=False,
    arrowsize=1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by keeping the arrow option but modifying the arrow so it doesn't look like an arrow as follows:

```
arrows=True,
arrowsize=0,
arrowstyle='|-|'
```

The `arrowstyle` option changed the "arrow" to a flat cap which connects nicely to the node border. Read more about `arrowstyles` [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle)

The result looks like this which is what I wanted!

[image]